# python ;list indexing with variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, for-loop, while-loop

I'm trying to index a string from a start position that changes with every counter until the end and add those substrings to a list. However, when I try indexing the string with these variables that represent integers, it says the index values must be integers.

```
def sentence_splicer(string,number):
     string = str(string)
     k = int(number)
     n = len(string)

     number_of_strings = n//k

     string_list = []

     counter = 0
     while len(string_list) < number_of_strings:
         for i in string[counter:n]:
         substring = []
         substring.append(i)
         substring.append(' ')
         string_list.append(substring)
         counter += k
```

How can I accomplish this with variables?

Comment: The issue is that your variables are referring to non integers, as the error message tells you

Comment: which one is a non int?

Comment: I ran your code, it works fine,can you share the input which you checked?

Comment: I don't know. You must provide a [mcve]

Comment: sentence_splicer('University',2)

Comment: Consider using enumerate() function to achieve this. e.g. if ls="strstrstr", use for loop with enumerate like. "for i,s in enumerate(ls): print(i,s)"

Comment: What is supposed to be the expected output? I ve checked your code and it works fine.

Comment: @MT0820 sentence_splicer('University',2) it's also works fine